# Paymill bridge transaction error 525

Tags: paymill

Hey I'm using the paymill JS bridge to generate tokens and then send them to my backend...

Everything working fine with test API keys. Credit, SEPA, PayPal working like a charm.
I just tried to use the live API keys.
Unfortunately even though using valid visa credit card data I'm getting an error right from the bridge

```
{
  apierror:"unknown_error",
  message:"Transaction declined (525)"
}
```

Can't find anything in the docs talking about this error code. 
Does somebody know what's going on?

Comment: actually found the error.. I was only testing live keys and didn't want to charge the credit card too much, hence I tried to charge only 1 cent. 
Tried a greater amount and finally got a different error code; namely `110`.

Comment: I finally got a response by paymill. `525` is the error for too small of a amount. `110` is the error that's generated when the credit card is blocked for transactions by paymill to prevent fraud.